# Is it possible to connect an ubuntu laptop to a USB-C docking station over a USB-C to USB-A adapter and get signal in the monitors?

Tags: usb, dell, hp, displaylink, docking

I have a Dell WD15 docking station, and one of my laptops is a bit older so it does not have a USB-c port. When connecting that hp laptop (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS) I get the usb and audio connections, but there is no signal for the monitors. Is there a way to make this setup work, or is this hopeless?

Comment: This is a hardware question, not about Ubuntu specifically.

Comment: USB-A is not fast enough for a display signal. You need a USB-C which is compatible with the newer 3.1 standard.

Comment: @ToDo It's not about speed. It's about [USB C DP Alt mode](https://www.benq.com/en-us/knowledge-center/knowledge/usb-c-introduction-what-is-dp-alt-mode.html). In short, sending DP over a USB-C-connector.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't. It's hardware that is missing. USB C on many laptop supports [USB C Alt mode](https://www.benq.com/en-us/knowledge-center/knowledge/usb-c-introduction-what-is-dp-alt-mode.html) which is DP over USB C cable.

The sound is however a normal USB signal, and thus works perfectly fine over USB.

Answer (score 1):

It is hopeless.

Your USB C dock expects a video signal over the USB C cable, but your USB A to C adapter only repeats the USB 2.0 signals. Some also handle USB 3.0 signals.

To make your dock work, you have need an USB A to C adapter which has a graphical card build in to re-create the missing video signals from a standard like displaylink. If these would exist, they would cost about the same as a dock. (The reason USB C docks are cheaper, is because they don't need to convert the video signals

Answer (score 0):

My laptop is a Lenovo, and my docking station is USB 3.0 based system.

I've had success with DisplayLink software and

USB-C 3.1 Male to USB A Female Adapter OTG

which sells for about a dollar on ebay.

On the same docking station, I can remove the Lenovo and park a Mac with no loss of signal again using DisplayLink.

I can't say how that helps you with the Dell configuration. Have you read over the manual for your docking station?  There could be some BIOS settings to check.  https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics/esuprt_docking_stations/dell-dock-wd15_users-guide_en-us.pdf